# Should a large relationship be modeled in an entity in terms of readability and performance

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity that has a relation to a very large table ( > 100k Rows ). Now I am asking myself if I should express that relation really in my channel entity because  would never call getProducts directly to load all products into memory. I would rather go through a product repositiory and query for a very specific subset for that channel.

I have only put it there so it's more readable from a client perspective.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Channel")
public class Channel {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private List<Product> products;

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products= products;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

}
```

Comment: It all depends on what you need. If you don't need that relation in your entity for your application then don't put it in (you can always use a query as you already mentioned).

Comment: But wouldn't it be harder to see the context if this relationship was missing?

Comment: Why. What does it add to the `Channel` does the `Channel` need `products` to exists? Is it part of the `Channel`? Your relation model isn't your object model (and vice-versa).

Comment: It's just comfort. I would obtain an instance of a channel and can navigate through all of its assigned products. Sure channel can be standalone and doesn't need products to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put that in a entity definition at all. You see what is often missed is that name `@OneToMany` is very misleading. As there is no possibility to limit the number of items you are loading. It can practically be used only when Many means Few :). The Hibernate Guru [explains](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) it better then me

Of course the join is executed lazily meaning that as long as it is not used it will do no harm. But why tempt faith. Writing query in a repo gives you ability for pagination and you can narrow the results to the one you will truly need.

The other side of the equation is more useful. So if you have on the child entity annotation `@ManyToOne` leave it there. It is good if you update parent from context of a child.

Answer (score 0):

In short : no.

I think what you are asking may be opinion-based, but here is what I tend to do : remove all "non-navigable" relationships.

If you are using some generator to get JPA entities from a database model, the generator will create only bi-directional relationships. You need to remove all the relationships you will not used through the ORM mechanisms (for readability, maintainability and performance (in case someone would have the idea to remove the "lazy" indication or to call a getter on the collection in a transaction)).

For example, a User will be linked to a Language (many-to-one), but you don't want the (one-to-many) relationship between Language and User, even if at some point you will need to know in a report screen how many user speak which language.

Comment: So basically i would only put relations into my entites that are needed for the existance of those?

Comment: No, not exactly. Let's say a user has one-to-many emails, this relationship will be present (user.getEmails) but there will be use cases where emails are not needed to manipulate a user and won't be loaded. You put relationship when you may need to load in an automatic way (using entity graphs or a getter in a transaction). It's a purely technical criteria. This entity model is not exactly your conceptual model, because it has technical constraints.